# oracle group by different transaction ID

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to visualize my gridcontrol rows with block of operations with the transaction ID(TRXID). I want to add a column that for example trxID is 146 then 1 when 149 then 2 when 155 then 1 when 162 then 2.... With this column I will be able to visualize my block of rows with COLORCOLUMN. I will only use 2 different colors. Any suggestions?

```
TRXID COLUMN1 COLUMN2 COLORCOLUMN
144   ..      ..      1
144   ..      ..      1
144   ..      ..      1
151   ..      ..      2
151   ..      ..      2
167   ..      ..      1
167   ..      ..      1
167   ..      ..      1
185   ..      ..      2
190   ..      ..      1
```

here is my query:

```
                                     SELECT 
                                        D.TRX_ID TRXID,
                                        A.AGENT_NAME, 
                                        S.NAME SKILL_NAME,
                                        D.SKILL_LEVEL,  
                                        CASE D.CHANGE_TYPE WHEN 'DROP' THEN 'DÜŞÜRME' WHEN 'ADD' THEN 'EKLEME' END CHANGE_TYPE, 
                                        L.LOGIN_NAME,
                                        H.CHANGE_DATE,
                                        --COLORCOLUMN HERE 
                                     FROM CC_RTM_DBA.SKILL_CHANGE_DETAIL_HIST D,
                                        CC_RTM_DBA.SKILL_CHANGE_HIST H,
                                        CC_RTM_DBA.CFG_AGENT A,
                                        CC_RTM_DBA.CFG_SKILL S,
                                        CC_RTM_DBA.CFG_RTM_LOGIN L
                                     WHERE D.TRX_ID = H.ID
                                        AND D.AGENT_ID = A.ID
                                        AND D.SKILL_ID = S.ID
                                        AND L.LOGIN_ID = H.CHANGE_USER
                                     ORDER BY D.TRX_ID DESC, A.AGENT_NAME, SKILL_NAME, CHANGE_TYPE
```

and picture is here : 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use function [dense_rank()](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rank-dense-rank-first-last-analytic-functions) in combination with [mod()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions088.htm).

```
select trxid, mod(dense_rank() over (order by trxid), 2) as color from t
```

---

In the example below `dense_rank()` gives as values 1,1,1,2,2,3,4. `mod()` changes even values to 1 and odd to 0.

```
with t as (select 144 trxid, '..' c1, '..' c2 from dual union all
           select 144 trxid, '..' c1, '..' c2 from dual union all
           select 144 trxid, '..' c1, '..' c2 from dual union all
           select 151 trxid, '..' c1, '..' c2 from dual union all
           select 151 trxid, '..' c1, '..' c2 from dual union all
           select 167 trxid, '..' c1, '..' c2 from dual union all
           select 185 trxid, '..' c1, '..' c2 from dual)
select trxid, c1, c2, mod(dense_rank() over (order by trxid), 2) as color from t

trxid  c1  c2  color
144    ..  ..      1
144    ..  ..      1
144    ..  ..      1
151    ..  ..      0
151    ..  ..      0
167    ..  ..      1
185    ..  ..      0
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to change "color" when the column TRXID change value. Correct?

If so you can try:

```
select trxid, ... ,
       LAG(trxid, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY trxid), --this is the previous value
       CASE WHEN trxid != LAG(trxid, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY trxid)
            THEN 2
            ELSE 1 END as COLORCOLUMN;
from yourtable
order by trxid;
```

Sorry i can't test it.